# como mejorar consulta SQL con syBase?

Tags: sql, sybase

me gustaría optimizar o mejorar estas consultas que tengo en SQL, entregan los resultados esperados, pero encuentro que son demasiado largas no se que opinan alguna sugerencia o mejora que pueda hacer para reducir las líneas ya que después tengo que pasar esa consulta a criteria API .

```
SELECT DISTINCT g.gru_cod, g.gru_des
FROM odepa.dbo.T_grupo g, odepa.dbo.T_grupo_producto gp, odepa.dbo.producto p, odepa.dbo.precio_diario_oficial pd 
WHERE g.gru_cod = gp.gru_pro_gru_cod and 
gp.gru_pro_ori_cod = p.pro_ori_cod and 
gp.gru_pro_eco_cod = p.pro_eco_cod and 
gp.gru_pro_var_cod = p.pro_var_cod and 
gp.gru_pro_tip_cod = p.pro_tip_cod and 
gp.gru_pro_sec_cod = p.pro_sec_cod and 
gp.gru_pro_sse_cod = p.pro_sse_cod and 
gp.gru_pro_cla_cod = p.pro_cla_cod and 
gp.gru_pro_scl_cod = p.pro_scl_cod and 
p.codigo = pd.codigo_producto
order by g.gru_cod
```

```
SELECT DISTINCT  gp.gru_pro_gru_cod, v.var_cod, v.var_des 
FROM odepa..T_variedad v, odepa..T_producto tp, odepa..T_grupo_producto gp, odepa..producto p, odepa.dbo.precio_diario_oficial pd 
WHERE tp.pro_var_cod = v.var_cod and 
tp.pro_ori_cod = gp.gru_pro_ori_cod and 
tp.pro_eco_cod = gp.gru_pro_eco_cod and 
tp.pro_var_cod = gp.gru_pro_var_cod and 
tp.pro_tip_cod = gp.gru_pro_tip_cod and 
tp.pro_sec_cod = gp.gru_pro_sec_cod and 
tp.pro_sse_cod = gp.gru_pro_sse_cod and 
tp.pro_cla_cod = gp.gru_pro_cla_cod and 
tp.pro_scl_cod = gp.gru_pro_scl_cod and 
gp.gru_pro_ori_cod = p.pro_ori_cod and 
gp.gru_pro_eco_cod = p.pro_eco_cod and 
gp.gru_pro_var_cod = p.pro_var_cod and 
gp.gru_pro_tip_cod = p.pro_tip_cod and 
gp.gru_pro_sec_cod = p.pro_sec_cod and 
gp.gru_pro_sse_cod = p.pro_sse_cod and 
gp.gru_pro_cla_cod = p.pro_cla_cod and 
gp.gru_pro_scl_cod = p.pro_scl_cod and 
p.codigo = pd.codigo_producto AND 
order by v.var_des
```

Comment: Demasiado largas en cantidad de líneas o es que tardan mucho tiempo?

Comment: cantidad de líneas, el tiempo es el esperado.
aunque nunca esta demás optimizar los tiempos

Comment: Y si esas son las relaciones entre las tablas, como esperas escribir menos lineas?

Comment: igual todos los joins en la primera no tienen ningun sentido, si no los usas para filtrar ni para obtener datos de las otras tablas....

Comment: La cosa está en la normalización. Si la relación entre las tablas pasa por esos campos, no hay mucho que hacer. Lo único seríá seguir normalizando y tratar de reducir la cantidad de info duplicada, poniendo esos `_cod` en una tabla y representándolos con un único campo PK... pero todo esto es acá hablando basura porque no conozco el modelo ni las entidades ni el negocio ;)

Comment: sacando todas esas comparaciones en la primera consulta me entrega una valor mas que no necesito, ahí tengo que buscar la forma de reducir eso. Gracias @gbianchi

Comment: y nosotros como podriamos ayudarte, sin saber eso?? a tu pregunta le faltaria mucha informacion ;)

Comment: Si estoy viendo que información puede del útil para agregar.